# Use/convert a string to template in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a map of templates like this:

```
public map = {
    hi: `hi ${name}`,
    bye: `bye ${name}`
  }
```

but I need to apply the name variable after the declaration of the map.
I found a way, declare the templates as a string and do `` eval("`"+template+"`") ``  but this is uggly.

There is a way to specify when the templates apply the template? there is a way to convert a string to a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `map` as a function that returns an object:

```js
const map = (name: string) => ({
    hi: `hi ${name}`,
    bye: `bye ${name}`
  })

map('Squid') // { "hi": "hi Squid",  "bye": "bye Squid" }
```